# License Verification Library on Marshmallow and above

Tags: android, eclipse

Since Google needs all  new uploads to Google Play to use at least api level 26 or above (Android 8.0) I'm trying to get the License Verification Library (LVL) library to work.

But the LVL uses the org.apache.http and it has been deprecated and removed in Android 8.

When downloading the LVL with Eclipse there is only the same version with revision 1.

Is there a newer version to be found somewhere or has anybody a fix to how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.http.NameValuePair no longer available with compileSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958826/org-apache-http-namevaluepair-no-longer-available-with-compilesdkversion-23)

Comment: No it is not just to find a replacement for NameValuePair as the whole library needs to be updated. I want to find an updated version of the library itself.

Comment: Can you link which LVL library you're finding then?

Comment: It is the Google Play Licensing Library rev. 1 as found in the Extras in the Android SDK Manager

Comment: It looks like from this link https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up that there should be a revision 2 somewhere but I don't know how to make it show in eclipse Android SDK manager

Comment: You shouldn't be using Eclipse. It's been deprecated since 2015 for Android development.

Comment: Ok that might be the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi did you find a solution to the problem? Did using some other dev environment instead of eclipse solve the problem or at least get you the required LVL library?

Comment: Yes, I installed Android Studio, but I had to copy the licensing library source directly into my project as it didn't figure out to include it in the buildpath. But now it works.

The Android plugin for Eclipse is not supported anymore by Google

Comment: Ok. Which licensing library source did you use because the one which was downloaded by the ADT SDK manager seems to have some deprecated code? Is there a new version available? Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that difficulty. It seems that the version from Android studio is also version 1, but if I'm not mistaken this github repo should be it: https://github.com/google/play-licensing

The directory you are interested in is the com.google.android.vending.licensing

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody else comes by here I just wanted to share the link to the github with an updated version of License Verification Library on Github: [github.com/google/play-licensing](http://github.com/google/play-licensing)

Just copy it directly into your project. The directory you are interested in is the com.google.android.vending.licensing (Keep the directory structure).

Android Studio seem to still have version 1 of this which I don't understand, as some Google docs shows a version 2.