# My app from Play Store with License Verfication Library crashes when internet is on, on newer versions of Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, android-lvl

Recently I implemented License Verfication Library to my app using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852617/google-play-licencing-for-an-android-app-in-android-studio) answer and updated my app with it. However, I had to unpublish it because it started to crash on Android 9 and 10 devices when internet is on. If internet is off, the app doesn't crash but is `Not Licensed` as I removed `abort()` method from the code. However, the app is licensed and works well on Android 6 device. I suspect that this is because I added deprecated library:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

to library's gradle file. From Jinu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433687/android-gradle-apache-httpclient-does-not-exist/40043124#40043124) I understand that Android 6 is the last version I can use this library with. The error I'm getting if I don't add this library:

```
error: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

Does anybody know how can I make License Verification to work with later Android versions?

Comment: not marking this as a duplicate, simply asking if [this does not answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260756/license-verification-library-on-marshmallow-and-above)

Comment: I think, it does. Thanks a lot!